# Optimize PHP function to sort registrations

Tags: php, optimization

I have a function, which look like this:

```
function combineFixedpriceRegistrations($regsDates, $regsMonths, $dateFrom, $dateTo) {

   // A counter
   $cnt = 0;

   // A datelooper
   $dateLoop = $dateFrom;

   // An array for the registrations
   $regs = array();

   // While it has not past the date
   while ($dateLoop <= $dateTo) {

      // Check if it is the first and the monthly registrations has not been added
      if (date('j', $dateLoop) == 1) {

         // For each monthly registration
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($regsMonths); $i++) {

            // Set the registration
            $regMonth = $regsMonths[$i];

            // Check if the date is before or equal to the date
            if (strtotime($regMonth->getDate()) <= $dateLoop) {

               // Clone the object
               $regCloned = clone $regMonth;

               // Set the date
               $regCloned->setDate(date('Y-m-d', $dateLoop));

               // Add the registration
               $regs[] = $regCloned;
            }
         }
      }

      // While there are registrations for dates
      while ($cnt<count($regsDates)) {

         // Check if the date matches
         if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($regsDates[$cnt]->getDate())) == date('Y-m-d', $dateLoop)) {

            // Add the registration to the array
            $regs[] = $regsDates[$cnt];

            // Add 1 to the counter
            $cnt++;

         // Otherwise the dates does not match
         } else

            // Break out
            break;
      }

      // Add 1 to the date
      $dateLoop = strtotime('+1 day', $dateLoop);
   }
}
```

Can anybody figure out how to optimize it?

I will of course explain it further, if it is necessary

Comment: Please do explain it further. This is more a kind of fix-this-for-me kind of question. Explain where you think there are problems and what you expect.

Comment: I think it could be optimized with deleting some of the loops

Answer (score 1):

this is more a comment than an anwer, but it's too long for a comment. please forgive me.

it looks like you're relatively new to coding, and it's nice to see someone really wants to do things right from the first moment on: you're writing a lot of comments - like everyone should do - but most people don't.

but: 90% of your comments are completely senseless - things like...

```
// Clone the object
$regCloned = clone $regMonth;

// Add 1 to the counter
$cnt++;

// Break out
break;
```

...shouldn't need any kind of comments - those things are clear just by writing readable code.

comments shouldn't rewrite every line of code in plain english, this doesn't give any more information than the code itself. you should better use comments to explain *why* you're doing something, not *what* you're doing (in general, but of course there are obvious exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a `for` loop over the `count()` of an array where the only use of the loop variable is to pull the next value out of the array like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($regsMonths); $i++) {
    $regMonth = $regsMonths[$i];
    // ... doesn't use $i again ...
}
```

You can simplify the code and improve its performance ever so slightly with this

```
foreach ($regsMonths as $regMonth) {
    // ...
}
```

If you need the index `$i` elsewhere in the loop, use

```
foreach ($regsMonths as $i => $regMonth) {
    // ...
}
```

This will improve code readability more than performance. When optimizing code, measure first, and attack the algorithm. It always helps to clearly state the purpose of the code. Comments like

```
// A datelooper
$dateLoop = $dateFrom;
```

mean little. You would be better served by documenting the intent of the method in a paragraph or two.

Comment: I can't use the foreach loop, when I need to clone the object.<br />Oh, the datelooper is just used in the while loop, so I didn't think it needed any comments

Comment: @The87Boy - There is no restriction on cloning the key and values within a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Then I do not know, why I could not clone it, when I was using foreach, but when I changed to for loop I could